# Study of the Consequences of C++ warnings

Tags: c++, warnings

I just started work at a job that has very old code, compiling this code with even basic warnings enabled produces thousands of warnings, many of them are really scary to me. Much of this code was written in the 80s, so management is not excited to have some new engineer try to fix it.

My opinion is that it should be a high priority to get rid of these warnings, but I don't have any data to back me up. I understand management's thoughts that fixing all the warnings is a serious undertaking, and may not be worth the effort on code that appears to work as is. I'm looking for a study that points to bugs/warning or something like that so I can go to them and say something like: "We have 200,000 warnings, and from study X, it's likely that there are 2,000 bugs hidden in there."

Very similar discussion here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111616/handling-false-positives-and-legacy-code-warnings-in-static-analysis-of-c-code

I don't think that this should be closed due to off-topic because it is a: "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession."

This was closed due to off-topic, but I found a study: http://institute.lanl.gov/isti/irhpit/presentations/ensuring-sq.pdf
http://collaboration.csc.ncsu.edu/laurie/Papers/TSE-0197-0705-2.pdf

Comment: What about writing some unit tests and actually get rid of those bugs ? If you're ever going to rewrite this, you'll need tests.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what industry still has a code base from the 80s? At some point any reasonable company will opt to rewrite it.

Comment: I'm trying to convince management that warnings are a problem, not that a particular bug needs a test. It takes longer to write a test than to initialize a value (for example); management needs a good argument to allow me to fix warnings, unit tests won't help me convince them.

Comment: If you take 3 warnings in the list and write tests that show that they are indeed bugs, that would be convincing.

Comment: +1 Good point, that's worth a shot. Still, I'm interested in data pointing to how bad a warning is -- if only for my own interest. Also, I'm afraid that they will say something to the effect of: "ok, fix those, but only those."

Comment: @Dave quite a few, e.g. automation industry. I see regularly code with the comment 1983 at the top of the file

Comment: @Dave - actually, re-writing is almost never a good idea, if the code works. If you want a case study take Netscape - they stopped developing for a few years to re-do their browser, and effectively gave up the market. There's still plenty of COBOL that started life in the 70s, and my last job was working on a program that started life in pure C, running on an embedded 68000 in the 80's. When last I touched it, it had evolved into a C++ program running as a multi-threaded process under Linux. With never a re-write in it's history.

Comment: @MichaelKohne 1 example that could be due to anything does not make a case study. Even having off the charts amazing code quality legacy cruft will build. Especially when considering a span of decades, where practices, languages, and standard libraries change dramatically.

Comment: @Dave - the problem is that if you are re-writing, you aren't adding new features, or fixing bugs, or participating in any way in your market. So if you decide to do a total re-write on a non-trivial piece of software, you are basically going dark for a long period of time. When you emerge, the new software will have new and different bugs, and will in some ways be unfamiliar - if you had any competition, they'll have leaped past you because you've been standing still. It's not that a re-write is bad for the software, it's that a re-write is bad for the BUSINESS. Often fatal.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Re-design/Re-write an old enough crappy enough code base and you'll see very significant long term improvements. Maintainability. Ease of adding new features. A company should have the money to simultaneously have a new code effort and support the old code (a new code effort doesn't mean throw everything out, if there are good pieces you can keep them, or refactor them). If it doesn't, and is decades old, it's probably just about out of business anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there are any such studies. I'm also going to go out on a limb here and say that management is right - trying to fix all those warnings, simply to fix all those warnings, is a bad idea.

You WILL break things by fixing the warnings! Right now there's probably a lot wrong with that code, but there's a lot right with it, and for you go through and cause problems in 'working' code is NOT going to go over well.

In your shoes, I'd get to work on whatever modifications/fixes I need to do. In the process, write unit tests for EVERYTHING you touch, AND clear up the warnings for everything you touch.

I don't know what your build system is, but if it's possible, build everything you touch with warnings on, leaving warnings off for the older stuff, and move code you change into new 'clean compile' files.

You aren't going to get hold of it quickly, but you can't just jump in and change a bunch of stuff. You have to find a way to work that lets you make progress, without breaking things for the end users.

UPDATE:
I started this as a comment, but I think it deserves to be part of the answer.

Clean code (code that has no warnings, code that has unit tests, code that is easy to understand) IS NOT and should NEVER BE the goal of any developer who actually has to *get things done* in the real world.

Clean code is a TOOL that we use in order to make our products better and our lives (and the lives of those who follow in our footsteps) easier. It's a good tool, nay, a great tool, but it's JUST A TOOL.

If you lose sight of the actual goal (producing software that works), you can bog yourself down in the trivia associated with your process. That may feel good, but it generally doesn't satisfy the users, or ship the product on time.

Comment: Indeed, every time we fix warnings for a new version of some compiler, we introduce bugs in the process (most of the time some tests eventually catch those, but still).

Comment: I agree with almost everything you said, I know some things will stop working if I fix all the warnings; but I'd argue that these things aren't working now, it's just luck that it works -- my last change, something like changing "char p[124];" to "char p[124]={};" breaks things, but it's good (imo) to find that doing that breaks things. There is an underlying problem that is exposed by this change.

Comment: Agreed. Further, many warnings are about coding style; "fixing" them means changing working code to match some compiler writer's notion of good style. For example, GCC now warns that `a && b || c && d` needs parentheses. It doesn't. Don't mess with it.

Answer (score 1):

Warnings do not mean defects. Every product that is not thoroughly enough tested contains defects. If product is well tested then there are no defects.

Lot of warnings are bad for other reason. The warnings hide new warnings (that may indicate freshly made defects) from maintenance. So maintenance of code with lot of warnings is more expensive.

Fixing warnings and sometimes even real defects like memory leaks should be done with care. It should never be done mechanically. That will most likely break working product. That I have seen tens of times in practice.

Comment: Your first line is just ridiculous, almost every product, no matter how thoroughly tested it is has defects. And actually many warnings that are introduced in newer compilers often point to constructs that could be bugs, and often are bugs, unless the programmer knew very well what he was doing. Getting rid of this is always better than not, unless the product is completely unmaintained.

Comment: Every product that is not thoroughly enough tested contains defects. Irrelevant if there are warnings or not. So warnings do not mean defects.

Comment: Yes, what I said does not contradict with your words by formal logic. Warnings may, but do not mean defects and first line was accurate.

Comment: Every software product has defects.

Comment: @JohnDibling That is not true. There are software products that do not contain defects. For example most std::vector implementations are defect free by now.

Comment: Even the std lub has defects. There are thousands of defect reports.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with most of what Michael Khone says, but quite a bit of product/development management is involved here and the evaluation depends on this. Some (but not all) major questions you should ask yourself:

1. What is the development mode of this product? Is it just bugfixes with minor enhancements from time to time or are you constantly developing new features on it.
2. Is there decent enough test coverage? Undertaking major rewrites as this is suicide if you don't have a decent regression suite. Even then a few bugs will still slip through, but it's much better than nothing.
3. Is there a need to update the toolchain/platform? This is important because many warnings are actually things that will not show any problem as long as you stick to the same environment where you're sure this "problematic" behavior is predictable (and probably correct for your code). If however you want to change one of these drastically, it might be a very good idea to invest time in solving all those warnings.

So warnings -> bugs depends much on your actual product.

Comment: Good questions.  1: Constantly developing new features 2: Almost no test coverage. 3: We plan on changing compilers and platforms in the semi-near future.

Answer (score 0):

The sad truth is that fixing old code is more often than not a fruitless adventure. Old code has often no unit tests and people who wrote the code are long gone from the company. If you see some weird thing in the code it may have been done for a particular reason but so many factors have changed since then that it is just difficult to do any impact analysis. There are just too many things that can go wrong when rewriting old code. Instead what you should focus on is to write *new* code in a good style.

Another issue is that management has absolutely no understanding why code should be rewritten, for them code is functionality - period